# Hide a server side control from custom control's code behind file in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a server side div tag in my za.aspx page which contains a label and dropdownlist

```
<div id="SkillsStatus" runat="server" style="display:none">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Please select a skill" 
        Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False" Font-Size="Larger"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="SkillsStatusddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
        onselectedindexchanged="SkillsStatusddl_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        CssClass="selectpicker">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Choose An Option</asp:ListItem>

    </asp:DropDownList>
```

now, i am binding data to dropdownlist at codebehind file, with that i am binding a cusom control in code behind file

```
 PreChatSurvey customPrechatSurvey = new PreChatSurvey
    {
        ID = "customPrechatSurvey",
        ForeColor = Color.Black,
        SurveyId = 0,
        IsPreview = false
    }; 

     protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {


        SkillsStatus.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block");
            SkillsStatusddl.DataSource = "";
            orgID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["OrgID"]);

            DataSet ds = SubCampaignBase.GetSkillStatus(orgID);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                ListItem li = new ListItem();
                li.Text = row["SubCampaignName"].ToString();
                li.Value = row["SubCampaignId"].ToString();
                li.Attributes.Add("data-icon", "glyphicon glyphicon-user");

                if (Convert.ToBoolean(row["soa_status"]))
                {
                    li.Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "green");
                    li.Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "white");
                }
                else
                {
                    li.Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "black");
                    li.Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "white");

                }

                SkillsStatusddl.Items.Add(li);

            }
         base.OnInit(e);

        }
```

now it loads a custom control and dropdown on same page, this custom control have a button, and on that button click, i want to hide the div tag containing the dropdown so i write following on button click

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            DropDownList dd = (DropDownList)this.Parent.FindControl("SkillsStatusddl");
            dd.Enabled = false;
            HtmlGenericControl div = (HtmlGenericControl)this.Parent.FindControl("SkillsStatus");
            div.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
    }
```

For safety, i have tried two things,
But nothing is working, neither the div gets disappear nor dropdown gets disabled

Comment: have you tried `div.Visible = false;`

Comment: Yes i have already tried, but not working

Comment: Have you debugged through the button click code? Is `FindControl` finding right controls?

Comment: Yes, i have debugged the code and it is getting right controls and making them disable/disappear at that moment

Comment: When you say custom control, do you mean  a user control in your aspx page?

Comment: Can you post the styles under `CssClass="selectpicker"`?

Comment: I am using a cs file which fetches control id from database and accordingly creates controls i.e textbox, button,etc., as a custom control and the cssclass selectpicker is not defined by me, it is provided by bootstrap which is i am using.

Comment: On button click, the page is not get refreshed or postback, could it be the reason?